# building a multi-tenant mongoDB database initially, but later remove it

Tags: mongodb, multi-tenant

I have a design issue that i'm facing and because i am relatively new to mongodb i think i need some help to make the right decision.

problem:

i am building a type of social networking website for let's call group A consumers.  I also need to build this same type of website for group B consumers.  initially, i want to keep them separate with no interaction/sharing between the two groups but i do not want to maintain two separate websites.  so a multi-tenant solution is ideal.  the tricky part of this problem is that at SOME point in the future, i want to create a website for BOTH group B and A consumers, essentially merging them into 1 website.  this 1 website will have all users from the original groups A and B but now they can all see each other, interact with each other, friend each other, etc.

is the right path to first create a multi-tenant mongo database, then later how easy is it to remove this multi-tenancy?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you do not create and drop the databases. Instead you can have the application with 2 tenants like facebook and g+ with their own set of users. However at some point of time in the future, you can just share your facebook user to g+ or the otherwise. in this case, there is no need to drop / merge tenant based tables or database and they will remain intact.

Your application should have the multi-tenancy capabilities that enable user sharing across tenants or linking users across tenants and that is the sure shot approach.